# What language and data structures does MYSQL uses as backend?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am just curious to know what data structures and languages does MYSQL exactly use as back end language? and what does the file format **.MYD** , **.MYI** and **.frm** stand for and how does MYSQL use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can be compiled in C/C++ and you can download the source code to do so.

At [this link](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads), Under the Select Platform ComboBox, Select `Source Code` and Download it from there

The `.frm` , `.MYD`, and `.MYI` make up a [**MyISAM table**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/myisam/info)

For example, the user table for the mysql grants is amde up of three files

- /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.frm (Table Structure for any Storage Engine)
- /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYD (MyISAM Table Data)
- /var/lib/mysql/mysql/user.MYI (MyISAM Table Indexes)

Comment: @RonaldoMySQLDBA thanks for the reply. It was quite helpful.